# Pushing data to browser from ubuntu server

Tags: ajax, perl, ubuntu, push-notification, push

I have a web application which is pretty much a web scraper. The web scraper script is called from the client's browser through an ajax call(basically initiating a PHP script which then calls a Perl script to do the heavy lifting). Because the script is scraping a lot of data it takes up to a minute or two for it to finish. I am trying to figure out what is the best way to push data live from the perl script to the user's browser to show some sort of 'progress' instead of just showing loading animation for a minute or two.
The application is hosted on my own Ubuntu VPS so I can use any technology I like. What is the best way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already are using perl, you might consider turning your script into an "asyncronous" application that scrapes and can "push" some kind of update while doing so using perl. You could use something like [Mojolicious](http://www.mojolicio.us), or one of the many Plack/PSGI server alternatives (*e.g*: [Twiggy](https://metacpan.org/pod/Twiggy), [Starlet](https://metacpan.org/pod/Starlet), [Kelp](https://metacpan.org/pod/Kelp) *etc.*, *c.f.* **[CPAN](http://www.metacpan.org)**) This will allow you to run your script as a separate application.

It might be a bit tricky to update a page with partial scraping results, but if you can figure out how to make your scraper run this way from tutorials and "How To" type articles such as these:

- [Mojolicious Cookbook](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook) example approaches to solving problems - when I RTFM I like to start here.
- [Basic Mojolicious AJAX example](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1051389) simple one file example. See the [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/) and [Twiggy](https://metacpan.org/release/Twiggy) docs and examples as well.

and reviewing discussions about using them:

- [Writing websocket chat using Mojolicious Lite](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/wiki/Writing-websocket-chat-using-Mojolicious-Lite) (for chat there is now Convos)
- [PSGI, AnyEvent, Twiggy](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1081564) ... recounts a perlmonk's adventure with these tools
- [Mojolicious websocket with server-side repeating events](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1070002). In your case client/server requests would be running the events but this might be useful as an example of debugging.

.. you could then hook your updated script into your existing server infrastructure. One way to do this would be by connecting your shiny new "websocket script" to a directory (using an Apache directive like `ProxyPass` or its equivalent) where it would be accessible to the client requests.

--

See also [**@creaktive**'s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1818793/creaktive) example for an ["ultimate" answer to the web scraper in Modern Perl question](http://blogs.perl.org/users/stas/2013/01/web-scraping-with-modern-perl-part-1.html) at *http://blogs.perl.org* ...

Comment: Twiggy is a server, how would it be helpful in the same way as a Mojolicious app?

Comment: Was thinking the OP could running the scraping application in separate environment as a server instead of as a script. Perhaps specifically mentioning Twiggy doesn't help here though.

Comment: While I would recommend Mojolicious, if you wanted to recommend an alternative, you might just mention PSGI. Deployment options beyond that are plentiful, Twiggy among them.

Comment: @creaktive has been added too :-)

Comment: fyi, I formalized my answer to @creaktive as a gist here: https://gist.github.com/jberger/5153008

Answer (score 2):

You can use nodejs and the progress plugin (https://www.npmjs.org/package/progress)